# How can I fix this python error "global name 'create_question' is not defined"

Tags: python, django

I'm following the tutorial for Django testing. Pycharm is throwing me errors from the code in test.py.

```
create_question
```

in the

```
QuestionViewTests(TestCase)
```

and

```
QuestionIndexDetailTests(TestCase) class's have are all throwing errors. But the 

create_question
```

inside of the

```
QuestionMethodTests(TestCase)
```

class works. I have both typed and copy and pasted and it still does not work. I also tried File > Invalidate Caches... and restarting PyCharm but that also didn't work. I am also confused about the classes

```
 QuestionViewTests(TestCase)
```

and

```
QuestionIndexDetailTests(TestCase)
```

are they to be inside the first class listed above

```
QuestionMethodTests(TestCase)
```

because the way it looks on the site I cant tell. I have moved both of them in and out of the class and it still doesn't work either way. any and all advice is welcome.

my code

```
    import datetime

    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.test import TestCase
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from .models import Question


    class QuestionMethodTests(TestCase):

        def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
            """
            was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
            pub_date is in the future.
            """
            time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
            future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
            self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

        def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
            """
            was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
            pub_date is older than 1 day.
            """
            time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
            old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
            self.assertEqual(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)

        def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_question(self):
            """
            was_published_recently() should return True for questions whose
            pub_date is within the last day.
            """
            time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
            recent_question = Question(pub_date=time)
            self.assertEqual(recent_question.was_published_recently(), True)

        def create_question(question_text, days):
            """
            Creates a question with the given `question_text` and published the
            given number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
            in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
            """
            time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
            return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)


    class QuestionViewTests(TestCase):
        def test_index_view_with_no_questions(self):
            """
            If no questions exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
            """
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
            self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

        def test_index_view_with_a_past_question(self):
            """
            Questions with a pub_date in the past should be displayed on the
            index page.
            """
            create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
            self.assertQuerysetEqual(
                response.context['latest_question_list'],
                ['<Question: Past question.>']
            )

        def test_index_view_with_a_future_question(self):
            """
            Questions with a pub_date in the future should not be displayed on
            the index page.
            """
            create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
            self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.", status_code=200)
            self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

        def test_index_view_with_future_question_and_past_question(self):
            """
            Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
            should be displayed.
            """
            create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
            create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
            self.assertQuerysetEqual(
                response.context['latest_question_list'],
                ['<Question: Past question.>']
            )

        def test_index_view_with_two_past_questions(self):
            """
            The questions index page may display multiple questions.
            """
            create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
            create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
            self.assertQuerysetEqual(
                response.context['latest_question_list'],
                ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
            )

    class QuestionIndexDetailTests(TestCase):
        def test_detail_view_with_a_future_question(self):
            """
            The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the future should
            return a 404 not found.
            """
            future_question = create_question(question_text='Future question.',
                                              days=5)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                       args=(future_question.id,)))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

        def test_detail_view_with_a_past_question(self):
            """
            The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the past should
            display the question's text.
            """
            past_question = create_question(question_text='Past Question.',
                                            days=-5)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                       args=(past_question.id,)))
            self.assertContains(response, past_question.question_text,
                                status_code=200)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indented your definition of create_question so it looks like a member of QuestionMethodTests. Essentially you did this:

```
class Foo:
    ...

    def create_question(x):
       ...

create_question(3)
```

When I *think* you meant to do this:

```
class Foo:
    ...

def create_question(x):
    ...

create_question(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your calls to `create_question` are called on an instance of `QuestionMethodTests`; it's not a global function, it's a method on instances of `QuestionMethodTests`, so you need to make a `QuestionMethodTests` object and call it. Of course, you left off the initial `self` argument in the definition of `create_question`, so even if you manage to call it, it won't work.

That said, it doesn't look like `create_question` even makes sense as a member function; moving it to the top level of the file (outside any class definition) is probably what you want here; it fixes the need to call it as an instance method, and you won't need to add `self` as a parameter.